# SHA-512 is it possible to get a collission in the first byte?

Tags: sha512

Is it possible to get a collision on the first byte of a hash generated with a SHA512? If so, how could this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the first byte can only have 256 different values.

If you generate 257 hashes, you must have a collision. Due to the Birthday paradox, you likely need to generate even less hashes (around sqrt(256) = 16).

It does not matter if it is SHA512 or some other hashing function for this.

Comment: what if wanted to collapse the first 4 bytes?

Comment: @tknbr Exact same answer but replace `256` with `4,294,967,295` (`16` gets replaced with `65,535`)

Comment: True, but you are trying to get a collision with a specific prefix, all 0's, instead of finding a collision of any prefix so you don't get the benefit of the Birthday Problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!